# Jest test randomly fails with "read ECONNRESET" without stack trace

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

I have a Jest test suite using Supertest, containing around 300 tests. Most of the time they all pass. However, sometimes a test fails, which appears to be completely random.

It fails with the following message:

```
read ECONNRESET
```

Nothing else is shown, no stack trace nor anything else. I have tried:

- The tests are interacting with a Postgres db, as well as Redis. The logs of both of these, show no errors
- Thinking that it could be some sort of uncaught Node.js error I added the following, which also didn't catch anything:

  ```js
  process
    .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
      console.error(reason, 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise', p);
    })
    .on('uncaughtException', err => {
      console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');
      process.exit(1);
    });
  ```

I am using:

- Node.js: v18.18.2
- Jest: 29.7.0
- Supertest: 6.2.4
- OS: macOS 10.15.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that there are actually 2 issues with `supertest`. One of them is related to Supertest's internals and one is related to the recommended usage of Supertest:

**Issue #1 - asynchronous startup**
When starting up a server with `supertest`, it is recommended by the `supertest` docs to repeat the following pattern for each test:

```js
request(app)
  .get('/user')
  .status(200);
```

The problem with this is that `supertest` is internally considering `app.listen()` to be a "synchronous" event, while really it is "asynchronous". This can occasionally create a race condition, where the request reaches the server, before it is ready to accept any. This issue was already reported in this [Github issue](https://github.com/ladjs/supertest/issues/566), but despite a good amount of upvotes, there seems to be no sign of this getting fixed.

Luckily, it is pretty easy to workaround this issue, by starting the server in advance and manually controlling its lifecycle:

```js
let server;
beforeAll((done) => {
  server = app.listen(0, '127.0.0.1', done);
});

afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});

test('Should get user', async () => {
  await request(server)
    .get('/user')
    .expect(200);
});
```

This way, the race condition mentioned above is eliminated and the `READ ECONNRESET` error should disappear.

**Issue #2 - incorrect port selection**
In addition to the `READ ECONNRESET` error, I also sometimes encountered a `400` status code with the `WebSockets request was expected` message.

It turns out that by default `supertest` picks a random free port to start the server on. However, `supertest` looks for a free port on `0.0.0.0`, while other services might use ports on a different host: `127.0.0.1`.

An example of this is the `VSCode` debugger. Because, it runs on a different host, `supertest` might select the same port the debugger is listening on. This results in the error above, as the request is now send to the debugger as opposed to the `server`.

The solution is to explicitly specify the `host` when starting up the server as mentioned in `Issue #1` above:

```js
server = app.listen(0, '127.0.0.1', done);
```

Because the `hostname` is now supplied, `supertest` will only use free ports on that `hostname`.

This "port selection issue" was found by the same person who opened the Github issue mentioned above [here](https://github.com/ladjs/supertest/issues/787).